# Hibernate Dependencies Explanation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I know below **three maven dependencies** for Hibernate :

First One is **plain Hibernate API** `(sesion,sesseionFactory )`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Second One in **Hibernate with JPA** `(entityManager)`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

What is this third dependency for ? 
Does second dependency not cover JPA part ? Why is this additional dependency ?

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Moreever `hibernate-core` has transitive dependency on other two ? (`hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api`)

Is that third dependency provides more powerfull APIs apart from `entitymanager` like `Criteria API`